# Dozer Bean Mapper Configuration with Collections and set-method attribute

Tags: java, xml, dozer

i habe a question concerning Dozer Bean Mapping. I have the follwing xml configuration parts (i don´t understand some of this facts):

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>
        entity.template.TemplateEntity
    </class-a>
    <class-b>dto.template.TemplateDto
    </class-b>
    <field>
        <a set-method="setLang" get-method="getLang">lang</a>
        <b set-method="setLang" get-method="getLang">lang</b>
        <a-hint>entity.template.TemplateLanguageEntity</a-hint>
        <b-hint>dto.template.TemplateLanguageDto</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

What is the concret meaning of "set-method="setLang" get-method="getLang""?

What does the Dozer Bean Mapper do in this part? There is no other configuration, which describes, how to two collection should be mapped?

```
<a-hint>entity.template.TemplateLanguageEntity</a-hint>
<b-hint>dto.template.TemplateLanguageDto</b-hint>
```

Does the Dozer Mapper map all fields automatically, which are founded by them if no configuration was set?

Thanks for helping !

Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *What is the concret meaning of "set-method="setLang" get-method="getLang""?*

Beans that might have unorthodox getter and setter methods, Dozer support user specified setter and getter methods.To make a bi-directional mapping in this case, look at the following example below.

The source field in element A specifies a custom setter method and getter method using attributes.

```
<field>
  <a set-method="placeValue" get-method="buildValue">value</a>
  <b>value</b> 
</field>
```

- *What does the Dozer Bean Mapper do in this part? There is no other configuration, which describes, how to two collection should be mapped?*

Understand the [Custom set() and get() methods dozer documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html).

Lets take for example if we are mapping a String to an ArrayList by calling the addIntegerToList() method.
    Note that this is defined as a one-way field type since we can not map an ArrayList to a String.

```
<!-- we can not map a ArrayList to a String, 
         hence the one-way mapping -->
    <field type="one-way">         
      <a>integerStr</a>
      <b set-method="addIntegerToList">integerList</b>
    </field>
```

- *Does the Dozer Mapper map all fields automatically, which are founded by them if no configuration was set?*

Yes, Dozer Mapper maps all the fields automatically from class-A to class-B `iff both the field names are same.`